# WooCommerce: how to wrap Recent products widget?

Tags: woocommerce

Using built-in WooCommerce widget "Recents products" displays a title (text) followed by an unordered list of products. Surprisingly these two main elements (the title and the list) are not wrapped in any container, making it hard to style, integrate into a theme and ultimately hard to use. There's no option either for that in the widget menu.

Still is there any way to wrap them I may have not thought of ?

Answer (score 2):

WooCommerce makes use of [Filters](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/hooks/) to help us override the HTML output by the default Widgets.

For example, the [WooCommerce Products](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-widgets/#section-1), which I believe is the one you are referring to makes use `woocommerce_before_widget_product_list` and `woocommerce_after_widget_product_list` filters. You can simply hook your functions and modify the default output. Something like this :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_before_widget_product_list', 'my_theme_before_widget_product_list', PHP_INT_MAX );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_after_widget_product_list', 'my_theme_after_widget_product_list', PHP_INT_MAX );

function my_theme_before_widget_product_list( $html ) {
    return '<div class="my-theme-product-list">' . $html;
}

function my_theme_after_widget_product_list( $html ) {
    return $html . '</div><!-- /.my-theme-product-list -->';
}
```

If you are using the widgets within a sidebar, you can use `before_widget`, `after_widget`, `before_title` and `after_title` arguments of [register_sidebar](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar) function.